# Mocking a method that returns dynamic return type with Moq

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

Given the following  interface:

```
public interface IApiHelper
{
   dynamic CallApi(string url);
}
```

I've delclared an instantiated a `Mock<IApiHelper> _apiHelperMock`

I'm trying to write a test that returns a Success = true property, to mimic a JSON result. My setup looks like this:

```
_apiHelperMock.Setup(o => o.CallApi(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((dynamic)new { Success = true });
```

However I get the following error when trying to run the test:
    **Moq.Language.Flow.ISetup' does not contain a definition for 'Returns'**

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to cast the anonymous type object to `dynamic`.

Try this:

```
_apiHelperMock
    .Setup(o => o.CallApi(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(new { Success = true });
```

Comment: Damn, that was good, 

like it's written under https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-signalr-applications 
   mockClients.Setup(m => m.All).Returns((ExpandoObject)all)

Answer (score 9):

I was able to create an `ExpandoObject` and cast it to `object`.

```
dynamic userInfo = new ExpandoObject();
dynamic user1 = new ExpandoObject();
user1.title = "aaa";
dynamic user2 = new ExpandoObject();
user2.title = "bbb";
userInfo.groups = new List<ExpandoObject> { user1 , user2 };

var endpointMock = new Mock<IRestEndpointHandler>();
endpointMock.Setup(c => c.RequestJsonDynamicGet(It.IsAny<Uri>())).Returns((object)userInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

OR just return `Dictionary<string,string>` :)